# Construct a graph such that the bound for X(G)+X(G') is tight.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have just proved the bound $\chi(G)+\chi(\overline{G})\geq 2\sqrt{n}$ but I would like to show that for every perfect square $n=k^2$, there exists a graph $G$ such that equality holds. I have found such graphs for $k=1$ and $k=2$ but I am having difficulty for the general case.

My strategy is to find graphs with $k^2$ vertices such that $\chi(G)=\chi(\overline{G})=k$.

Then I'd have $\chi(G)+\chi(\overline{G})=2k=2\sqrt{n}$

I was thinking that since $k^2\equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 (\text{mod }4)$ then I might be able to show there exists a self-complementary graph $G$ on $k^2$ vertices such that $\chi(G)=k$. I know that a self-complementary graph on $k^2$ vertices must exist but showing there is one with chromatic number $k$ is proving difficult.

Or maybe I am barking up the wrong tree and there is a simpler construction without the self-complementary part? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed making things more complicated than they have to be. Self-complementary graphs are trickier to find than the example you're looking for.

By far the most straightforward reason for a graph $G$ to have chromatic number $\chi(G) = k$ is if $G$ contains a clique $K_k$. It might be the case that $\chi(G) > k$ for some subtle reason; certainly $\chi(G)$ will not go any *lower*.

So if you want to construct a graph $G$ on $n = k^2$ vertices such that $\chi(G) = \chi(\overline G) = k$, the best place to start is from cliques. Find a graph $G$ that contains a clique of size $k$ (but not $k+1$) whose complement also contains a clique of size $k$ (but not $k+1$).

If you're willing to be spoiled on one possible answer, we can take $G$ to be

> the disjoint union of $k$ cliques of size $k$, making $\overline{G}$ the complete $k$-partite graph $K_{k,k,\dots,k}$.

More generally, think about what the color classes have to be. We have a partition of $V(G)$ into $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_k$ such that, for every edge $vw \in E(G)$, $v$ and $w$ are in different parts. (This is what a $k$-coloring of $G$ is.) Similarly, there's a partition of $V(G)$ into $B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \dots \cup B_k$ doing the same thing for $\overline{G}$.

If any two vertices $v$ and $w$ are in the same part $A_i$ and in the same part $B_j$, we're in trouble: the edge $vw$ is in either $E(G)$ or $E(\overline{G})$, making one of the colorings invalid. So this should never happen.

One way to do this is by choosing the parts $A_1, \dots, A_k$ to be
$$A_1 = \{1,2,\dots,k\}, A_2 = \{k+1,k+2,\dots,2k\}, \dots, A_k = \{k(k-1)+1,\dots,k^2\}$$
and choosing $B_1, \dots, B_k$ to be
$$B_1 = \{1,k+1,\dots,k(k-1)+1\}, B_2 = \{2,\dots,k(k-1)+2\}, \dots, B_k = \{k, 2k, \dots, k^2\}.$$
Then we just have to decide for each edge $vw$ whether it's in $E(G)$ or $E(\overline{G})$, in a way that's consistent with these colorings. A lot of the time, we have lots of freedom: for example, the edge $(1,k^2)$ can't mess either coloring up.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see that before. Thank you.